# In GitHub for Windows, how to stop tracking a repository when "stop tracking this repository' menu item is grayed out?

Tags: repository, github-for-windows

In my GitHub for Windows, there are two repositories that always appear on the list of GitHub repositories. One was created by me. The other was a project I stopped watching long ago.

I want to remove these items form the list of GitHub repos in GitHub for Windows.

When I move my mouse over the repo name, the pop-up menus says I can clone it etc, but 'stop tracking repository' is grayed out.

I have tried cloning the project. Then 'Stop tracking repository' is not grayed out. I click on this item. The repo does not disappear from the list of repos, but 'stop tracking...' is grayed out again,

Any suggestions on how to make these 'ghost' repos disappear from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stop Tracking" is always grayed when used on the GitHub repo associated to my account.
It works only for my "Local repositories".

If you have deleted your repo on the GitHub side (or stopped wathcing a repo), and a "refresh"  on the GitHub for Windows isn't enough to update your GitHub repo list, then you need to contact GitHub support.

Comment: Hi VonC 

You are probably correct in your observation. I will contact GitHub support...